# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 && Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: mysql, arrays, header

i am getting errors on my config.php file , it started giving me errors 1 day ago.
So the errors are:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/x/public_html/rx/includes/config.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/x/public_html/rx/includes/config.php:32) in /home/x/public_html/rx/includes/config.php on line 38

My config php file is the next:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
include 'functions.php';

$logged_in = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    $username = sec($_SESSION['username']);
    $password = sec($_SESSION['password']);

    $udata = get_row("SELECT * FROM playeraccounts WHERE playerName='$username' && playerPassword='$password'");
    if(isset($udata['playerID']))
    {
        $logged_in = 1;
        if(isset($_GET['logout']))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            mysql_query("UPDATE playeraccounts SET rpgon=0 WHERE playerName='$username'"); 
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
}
function redirect_not_logged()
{
    $username = sec($_SESSION['username']);
    $password = sec($_SESSION['password']);

    $udata = get_row("SELECT * FROM playeraccounts WHERE playerName='$username' && playerPassword='$password'");
    $id = $udata['playerID'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `playeraccounts` WHERE playerID = $id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
         $rpg = $row['rpgon'];
    }
    if($rpg == 0) 
    { 
        header('location: login.php');
    }

}

// vars
$member_types = array(
    'Civilian',
    'Los Santos Police Department',
    'F.B.I',
    'National Guard',
    'Paramedic Department',
    'Guvernment',
    'The Russian Mafia',
    'Grove Street',
    'Los Aztecas',
    'The Riffa',
    'Ballas',
    'Los Vagos',
    'Hitman Agency',
    'School Instructors',
    'Taxi Company',
    'News Reporters',
    'Las Barrancas Taxi Company',
    'Las Barrancas Paramedic Department'
);
$shop_types = array(0,
    'Bullet',
    'Cheetah',
    'FCR-900',
    'Clear 10FP',
    'Golden Account',
    'Infernus',
    'Change Nick',
    'Turismo',
    'Clear 1 Warn',
);
$rank = array(

    'Civil',
    'Rank 1',
    'Rank 2',
    'Rank 3',
    'Rank 4',
    'Rank 5',
    'Rank 6',
    'Leader'
);

$account_types = array(
    'No',
    'Yes' 
);

$status_types = array(
    '<font color="#FF0000">Offline</font>',
    '<font color="#0DFF00">Online</font>',
    '<font color="#FEC300">Sleep</font>'
);

$status1_types = array(
    '<font color="#FF0000">&#8226</font>',
    '<font color="#0DFF00">&#8226</font>',
    '<font color="#0DFF00">&#8226</font>'
);
$ban_type = array(0, 'N', 'I');
$admins56 = array(0, 'Trial Admin', 'Junior Admin', 'General Admin', 'Head Admin', 'Lead Admin', 'Manager');
$helpers56 = array(0, 'Trial Helper', 'Helper', 'Lead Helper');

?>
```

I can't find what is wrong , also the redirect_not_logged function isn't working anymore , since i get this 2 errors..

Comment: `$q` returns false, it means that you have incorrect table name (`playeraccounts`), incorrect column name (`playerID`) or one row above incorrect assignment `$id` var. What returns `echo "SELECT * FROM playeraccounts WHERE playerID = $id";`?

Comment: Why you choose using the first query ID and in the second query using this ID, from the same table, another data?

Answer (score 0):

playerID is the number of the row wich is situated in playeraccounts.